# How can I get collision with objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm making an html/javascript game that's basically space invaders (following a tutorial). In the tutorial, the guy gives the code for the the player (named tank) bullets hitting the aliens and aliens disappearing, but when the alien bullets hit the player (tank), nothing happens (he doesn't provide this code). Can someone please help me figure the code out?

This is the code he used for the player (tank) bullets hitting the aliens and the aliens disappearing when hit:

```
for (var j = 0, len2 = aliens.length; j < len2; j++) {
  var a = aliens[j];
  if (AABBIntersect(b.x, b.y, b.width, b.height, a.x, a.y, a.w, a.h)) {
    aliens.splice(j, 1);
    j--;
    len2--;
    bullets.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
    len--;
```

This is the function of the AABB intersection (i think we might need a new one):

```
function AABBIntersect(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
  return ax < bx+bw && bx < ax+aw && ay < by+bh && by < ay+ah;
};
```

Comment: A link to the original tutorial, and a snippet from the tutorial might be helpful for anybody who might try to answer this question.

Comment: Sure here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=krhkNzg6FPo&t=867s#t=222.119642 

This is the 2nd episode by the way. He inputs the damage and collision at around 16:20